# UIFont.fontName in iOS10 doesn't return "regular" suffix

Tags: swift, ios10, uifont

After a successful migration to swift 2.3 in my application, I found a font glitch.

I have an extension for `UIFont` where I change system font to my custom font.
In `iOS 9` and earlier everything worked as expected. In iOS 10 it doesn't.

The problem was in `self.fontName`. Normally it should return "fontName" + suffix for style (ex:regular, bold, etc).

However in `iOS 10` for regular the style, it doesn't return suffix only "fontName".

I googled to found why but couldn't find anything.
The problem is fixed but why this happens I don't know. Any idea?

Comment: `iOS` devs decided to drop suffix in font name. So what? Font names are intended for internal usage only. And what are you doing with raw font names anyways?

Comment: Didn't check, but you may want to use font descriptors instead of the name for the suffix. Plus, suffix isn't really only for the style, since it can contains the foundry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using font names has never been a good idea.

Use `fontDescriptor` and inspect the `UIFontDescriptor`'s `fontAttributes` and `symbolicTraits` to obtain information on the font in question. You can then create a new descriptor with modified attributes and/or traits, and obtain a font with that descriptor using `init(descriptor:size:)`.